# Clustering & Classify sparse large features

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cluster-analysis, classification

My problem `initial features` are **x** , **y** ,**theta**  that normalized in range[0,255].

For each `object` number of features is `variable`.

Clustering is applied so each cluster has number of features & each object belongs to `multiple clusters`.
In the predict stage ,compute clusters for each object from initial features(`new features`).

Each object belongs to a maximum of `10 clusters`.

Total number of clusters is `4000`.

If we consider new `features constant` for each object we have 4000 dimension that
it `very large for classify`.Only 10 features may be useful and my features is sparse.

**My question :**

Is there any way that we can classify these `sparse features` with best performance & which classifier is useful for it?
Note:I use locality sensitive hashing for classify new features with 4000 dimension that is very slow.

Comment: 4000 features is not a great deal if you use linear models, those scale up to millions of features. But it isn't clear from your problem if you're doing classification or clustering.

Comment: Please read the questions carefully.Total number of cluster is 4000.The number of clusters is dimension of new features.In the first step cluster the data in the next step classify membership of each object in the clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the **principal component analysis** for reduction of dimension of features to 10 dim then used the **SVM** for classification of new features & solved my problem.